# XML validation issues

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Hello I'm totally new in XML / XSD. Does anyone can help me out with this: 
XML (given):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <filmliste xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="filmliste.xsd"
           author="Max" datum="20.01.2016">
    <film>
        <titel> Movie</titel>
        <regiseur> abc </regiseur>
        <erscheinungsjahr> 2015 </erscheinungsjahr>
        <schauspieler> abc </schauspieler>
        <bewertung> abc </bewertung>
    </film>
    <film>
        <titel> Movie2 </titel>
        <erscheinungsjahr> 2015 </erscheinungsjahr>
        <regiseur> abc </regiseur>
        <schauspieler> abc </schauspieler>
        <genre> abc </genre>
    </film>
</filmliste>
```

My schema :

```
        <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="filmliste">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="film">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice  >
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="titel" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="regiseur" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:float" name="erscheinungsjahr" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="schauspieler" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:float" name="bewertung" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="genre"/>
            </xs:choice>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="author"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="datum"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now i have two validation errors in my XML document. 
1: Element 'regiseur': This element is not expected.
2: Element 'film': This element is not expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `xsd:choice` element is incorrect. It allows *only one* of the contained members to appear. That is, you can have a `titel` OR a `regiseur` but not both. Use either [`xsd:all`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256182%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (items appear in any order) or [`xsd:sequence`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256089%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (items appear in the specified order) instead. Judging by your XML, the order is not important so this should be `xsd:all`.
2. The default of `xsd:sequence@maxOccurs` is `1`. Therefore it is complaining at the second instance of `film`. Specify an appropriate maximum bound:

   ```
   <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you are using the `<xs:choice>` tag.
Using this tag means that you can only put in only one of the choices (child elements). Change it to either one of below tags.

`<xsd:all>` - the child elements can appear in any order.

`<xsd:sequence>` - the child elements can only appear in the order mentioned.